# including spaces while using %w

Tags: ruby, string, formatting

The following code produces the output "xyz"

```
a = %w{x y z} 
print a.to_s
```

Is there an option that can be added to the block to allow spaces to be added?

For example, I thought that by changing the code to this I might be able to space-separate the elements to produce an output of "x y z"

```
a = %w{"x " "y " "z "}
print a.to_s
```

Instead it produces this:

"x""y""z"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ["xyz"].split("").join(" ")
```

or

```
a = ["x","y","z"].join(" ")
```

or

```
a = %w(x y z).join(" ")
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do it this way. Thanks.

Comment: The problem you had is that array.to_s in Ruby before 1.9 just stuck all the elements end-to-end. The problem was not in your array data, but the method that printed the array. That's why %w{x y z}.join(' ') works fine.

Also, to include spaces in a %w array values, use "\ " (backslash-space).

Answer (score 6):

You can include spaces by backslash-escaping them (then adding an additional space as a separator).

```
a = %w{x\  y\  z\ }
```

This can become hard to read though.  If you want to put explicit quotation marks in there, you don't need `%w{}`, just use a normal comma-delimited array with `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `%w` for this--it's a shortcut for when you want to split an array from words. Otherwise, use the standard array notation:

```
a = ["x ", "y ", "z "]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def explain
  puts "double quote equivalents"
  p "a b c", %Q{a b c}, %Q(a b c), %(a b c), %<a b c>, %!a b c! # & etc
  puts

  puts "single quote equivalents"
  p 'a b c', %q{a b c}, %q(a b c), %q<a b c>, %q!a b c! # & etc.
  puts

  puts "single-quote whitespace split equivalents"
  p %w{a b c}, 'a b c'.split, 'a b c'.split(" ")
  puts

  puts "double-quote whitespace split equivalents"
  p %W{a b c}, "a b c".split, "a b c".split(" ")
  puts
end

explain

def extra_credit
  puts "Extra Credit"
  puts

  test_class = Class.new do
    def inspect() 'inspect was called' end
    def to_s() 'to_s was called' end
  end

  puts "print"
  print test_class.new
  puts "(print calls to_s and doesn't add a newline)"
  puts

  puts "puts"
  puts test_class.new
  puts "(puts calls to_s and adds a newline)"
  puts

  puts "p"
  p test_class.new
  puts "(p calls inspect and adds a newline)"
  puts
end

extra_credit
```